# Long response time in Neo4J query through rest api

Tags: java, rest, neo4j, neo4j-java-api

I have a RESTFul API which queries embedded neo4j database for recommendations for a user by hitting `http:IP_ADDRESS/myapplication/user/{userId}/recommendations`

I'm observing a very weird issue that for a particular user the response time to fetch the results (JSON) is quite high. It takes around 4 to 5 minutes. On the other hand for all other users who have even more number of friends the time is like fraction of seconds. Also i confirm that the recommendation logic is just finding nodes in the graph with same values as `userId`.

Comment: you can run the cypher query in web browser with prefix of 'EXPLAIN' and find the difference in execution plan. No way to get it over rest api call.

Comment: I analyzed the issue in the log file. It looks something of RAM size issue. The log shows `GC Monitor: Application thread blocked for so and so ms`. I think i need to tune it to appropriate JVM size. However, I don't know the value and ways to configure for embedded neo4j. How do you exactly do for embedded neo4j using java. My OS is linux. Do i just need to increase the heap memory of my server. Need suggestion.